# My Min value Button is not working, HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

MY code is not working, I need to find a min value from a list and I must use for, but for some reason it does not always work

```
<script>

  /* Example one */
  function findMin()
 {

    list = numbersBox.value.split(",");      // gets the input into an array form by splitting on ","
    var min = list[0];                       // assuming initially that min element is the first element

    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)     // for loop to go over all list elements starting from 0 to list.length
    {
         if(list[i] < min) min = list[i];                  // setting the min value appropriately
    }

    minBox.value = min;                     // setting answer into the minBox

}

</script>
```

```
<label>Write some numbers separated by commas:</label>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="numbersBox" />
<br><br>
<label>Minimum Value:</label>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="minBox" />
<br><br>
```

Find Min

Comment: When does it not work?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/185p0d7k/

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min):

```js
function findMin() {
  let numbersBox = document.getElementById('numbersBox');
  let minBox = document.getElementById('minBox');
  
  let numbers = numbersBox.value.split(',').map(n => parseInt(n));
  let min = Math.min(...numbers);
  
  minBox.value = min;
}
```

```html
<label>Write some numbers separated by commas:</label>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="numbersBox" value="9,6,12,67"/>
<br><br>
<label>Minimum Value:</label>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="minBox" />
<br><br>
<button onclick="findMin()">Find min</button>
```